# Idiom for 2 argument version of Condition#await(long, TimeUnit)

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

What's the idiomatic way of handling spurious wakeups when using the 2 argument version of Condition#await(long, TimeUnit)

I understand the zero argument version:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Scratch {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition flagSet = lock.newCondition();
    private boolean flag;

    void waitForever() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!flag) {
                flagSet.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void setFlag() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            flag = true;
            System.out.println("Flag set to true");
            flagSet.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        var scratch = new Scratch();
        var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.schedule(scratch::setFlag, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("Waiting for flag...");
        scratch.waitForever();
        System.out.println("Finished waiting");
        executor.shutdownNow();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

How would I change this so that I wait a maximum of 5 seconds while catering for the possibility of a spurious wakeup?

Comment: I don't think there is an "idiomatic" way.  That would imply that this problem occurs often enough for a recognizable idiom to emerge.  That's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it would be to get the clock time in the at the start of the `waitFor...` method. Then when you return from await and the condition is not satisfied, get the clock time again and compare it with the first time to decide if you need to await again.

The code could look something like this:

```
void waitForUpToFiveSeconds() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    long deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000L;
    try {
        flagSet.await(5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        while (!flag) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now >= deadline) {
                break;
            }
            flagSet.await(deadline - now, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

(It could probably be written in fewer lines of code, but I prefer to write code like this is a way that maximizes readability.)

Comment: If you want to wait until a `currentTimeMillis()` based deadline, you should use [`awaitUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#awaitUntil(java.util.Date)). If you’re interested in enforcing a correct elapsed time instead, you should use `System.nanoTime()`. Since this has an unspecified base and may roll over, you have to be careful not to compare two values but rather, calculate and check the difference: `long start = System.nanoTime(); while (!flag) { long elapsed = System.nanoTime(); if(elapsed >= …) break; … }`